# Datatables row.data() return undefined when click on expand button of a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to make an expanding row which show more detailed info about the participant data. but row.data() return undefined also the child element wont show up but no error at the console it just do nothing.

I'm using ajax to an API to obtain the participant data

i have tried placing on('click') inside the ajax request as i suspect it has something to do with the ajax call being asynchronous. but still no difference.

```
    function expandRowTemplate(rowData) {
        return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
            '<tr>'+
                '<td>Nomor Identitas:</td>'+
                '<td>' + rowData.identity_number + '</td>'+
            '</tr>'+
            '<tr>'+
                '<td>Ref. number:</td>'+
                '<td>' + rowData.reference_number + '</td>'+
            '</tr>'+
            '<tr>'+
                '<td>Agama:</td>'+
                '<td>' + rowData.religion + '</td>'+
            '</tr>'+
        '</table>';
    };
    $('#participantTable').DataTable({
        scrollX: true,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,       
        ajax: {
            url: '/echo/json/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: (data) => { data.json = ajaxResponse },
            dataFilter: (data) => {
                var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                json.recordsTotal = json.meta.pagination.total_data;
                json.recordsFiltered = json.meta.pagination.total_data < json.meta.pagination.item_per_page ? json.meta.pagination.total_data : json.meta.pagination.item_per_page;
                return JSON.stringify(json); // return JSON string
            },
            dataSrc: (resData) => {
                /* participantData = resData.data; */
                return resData.data;
            },
            error: (jqXHR) => {
                try {
                    let res = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
                    let messages = '';
                    res.meta.message.forEach(element => {
                        messages = messages + element;
                    });

                    alert(messages);

                } catch (e) {
                    /* xhrPool.abortAll(); */
                    console.log(e.message);
                }
            }
        },
        rowId: 'id',
        columns: [
            { 
                className: 'details-control',
                data: null,
                render: () => '<i class="far fa-plus-square"></i>',
                orderable: false,
                searchable: false
            },
            { title: 'ID', name: "id", data: "id" },
            { title: 'NAMA', data: "fullname" },
            { title: 'TEMPAT LAHIR', name: "place_of_birth", data: 'place_of_birth' },
            { 
                title: 'TANGGAL LAHIR', 
                name: "date_of_birth", 
                data: 'date_of_birth',
                render: (birthDateString) => { 
                    const birthDate = new Date(birthDateString);
                    const options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: '2-digit' };

                    const dateTimeFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('id-ID', options);
                    return dateTimeFormat.format(birthDate);
                }
            },
            { title: 'GENDER',name: "gender", data: "gender" },
            { title: 'ASAL SEKOLAH',name: "school", data: "school" },
            { title: 'TGL REGISTRASI', name: "registration_date", data: "registration_date" },
        ],
        order: [[1, 'asc']],
        language: {
            processing: '<div class="sk-three-bounce" style="margin: auto"><div class="sk-child sk-bounce1 bg-gray-800"></div><div class="sk-child sk-bounce2 bg-gray-800"></div><div class="sk-child sk-bounce3 bg-gray-800"></div></div>',
            searchPlaceholder: 'Search...',
        }
    });

    var table = $('participantTable').DataTable();

    $('#participantTable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var tr = $(this).parents('tr');            
        var row = table.row(tr);

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {            
            row.child.hide();
            $(this).children().removeClass('fa-minus-square');
            $(this).children().addClass('fa-plus-square');
        }
        else {
            console.log(row.data());

            row.child(expandRowTemplate(row.data())).show();
            $(this).children().removeClass('fa-plus-square');
            $(this).children().addClass('fa-minus-square');
        }
    } );
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hammam_afiq/byr89fhu/24).

i want the row can be expanded like this [example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)

Comment: check this line. It should be `var table = $('#participantTable').DataTable();`